# rsync freezes whole system

Tags: rsync, backup, freeze, crash

i am trying to backup a few TB to a second hdd. I am copying from a NTFS partition to an ext4 partition. Most of my files are small pictures. I use the command `rsync -av`. However after some random amount of time my system freezes completly. I need to press the power button. This happens every time when I restart the transfer. And the syslog also seems unsuspicious:

```
Jul 13 18:58:48 pop-os onedrive[2238]: Syncing changes and items from OneDrive ...
Jul 13 18:58:48 pop-os rtkit-daemon[1079]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 13 18:58:50 pop-os rtkit-daemon[1079]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
Jul 13 18:58:50 pop-os onedrive[2238]: Sync with OneDrive is complete
Jul 13 18:58:52 pop-os rtkit-daemon[1079]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 13 19:01:07 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul 13 19:01:07 pop-os systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 13 19:01:07 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore.
Jul 13 19:01:07 pop-os systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

My system config is the following: 16gb of ram, an i7-9700k, maximus x hero and a titan xp.

Edit: What I also find interesting is that my PC is going into sleep when rsync is copying and is therefore pausing the copy process.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @waltinator I have 16gb of ram and 20gb of swap

Comment: Neither `rsync`, nor NTFS could have caused this. I presume there's some HW failure, bad RAM maybe.

Comment: Empirically I would say that in my experience `rsync`, `cp` or any other tool that reads/writes large numbers of small files very rapidly, and any Linux-based implementation of NTFS, do not get on well together. Sadly I have been unable to provide a sufficiently robust method of triggering issues to report a meaningful fault

Comment: You mention in your edit about your PC going into 'sleep mode'. If you are copying large amounts of data, you might want to check your power settings and make sure the PC isn't being put to sleep/suspend if there is a period of inactivity.